# Show that all the solutions of the given differential equation are bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let $ f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a bounded and continuous function. Show that every solution of the differential equation $$y''+2y'+5y=f(t,)\quad t\ge 0$$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$.

By using the method of solution of Non-Homogeneous differential equation, I got the solution as $$y(t)=e^{-t}(C_1\cos 2t+C_2\sin 2t)+\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}f(t)$$
I understand that complementary function of the equation is bounded and can have maximum value as $(C_1+C_2)$ but I have no idea about Particular integral function $i.e. \frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}f(t)$

Any help is appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particular solution of the equation given by [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)  is $$K(x) =e^{-x}\left(-\frac {\cos2x}2 \int_0^x \sin(2t)f(t)e^t dt+\frac {\sin2x}2 \int_0^x \cos(2t)f(t)e^t dt\right)$$

All the solutions are therefore given by $K(x) + C\cos(2x) + D\sin(2x)$ where $C,D \in \mathbb R$

Note that if $f$ is bounded by some $M>0$, $$|K(x) + C\cos(2x) + D\sin(2x)|\leq |C|+|D|+e^{-x}M(e^x-1)\leq |C|+|D|+M$$

Comment: Can you elaborate that how you get that $e^{-x} M (e^x-1)$?

Comment: @Chiranjeev_Kumar $\left|-\frac {\cos2x}2 \int_0^x \sin(2t)f(t)e^t dt\right| \leq \frac 12 \left|\int_0^x \sin(2t)f(t)e^t dt \right| \leq \frac 12 M \int_0^x e^t dt $

Comment: @Chiranjeev_Kumar variation of parameters works everytime with this kind of problems